# Another way of drawing lines

Tags: java, matrix, line, draw, ppm

I have a program that generates a .ppm file with a bunch of black dots on it. What I want to do is to draw lines between these dots to build a graph, but instead of using some swing method I want to know if there is a way to do it by directly manipulating the .ppm's matrix.
I assume it would require some nested loops, but how would I identify which positions I need to change to create the line between two dots?

(for those who don't know, a .ppm file is basically a giant matrix with 3 RGB values for each of it's positions, allowing you to draw stuff pixel by pixel)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Comment: Search for _Java ImageIO portable pixmap format_; JAI had a plugin.

Comment: show us how you read the PPM - thats the starting point

Answer (score 0):

Single pixel thickness:

```
void drawline(Color pixels[][], int width, int height, 
               int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2, Color line)
{
   int dx = x1 - x2;
   int dy = y1 - y2;
   if (dx != 0 || dy != 0)
   {
      int n = Math.Max(Math.Abs(dx), Math.Abs(dy));
      double inv = 1.0 / (double)(n + 1);
      double dxdn = (double)dx * inv;
      double dydn = (double)dy * inv;
      double x = (double)x1, y = (double)y1;
      for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
      {
         int xi = (int)x, yi = (int)y;
         if (xi >= 0 || xi < width || yi >= 0 || yi < height)
            pixels[yi][xi] = line;
         x += dxdn; y += dydn;
      }
   }
}
```

(NB this is in C# syntax; you may need *minor* changes to convert it to Java)